# React Quill with React-Redux form validation not working properly

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-quill

Iam using antd form and ReactQuill in my code,

```
 <Col md={24} xs={12}>
                                <Form.Item initialValue='' name='Message' label="Message" required rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please enter message" }]}>
                                    <ReactQuill modules={modules} formats={formats}
                                        value={this.state.Message}
                                        onChange={(e) => {
                                            this.setState({ Message: e });
                                        }} />
                                </Form.Item>
                            </Col>
```

This is my code, I added validation for this field, in sometimes validation goes wrong. If I entered the value, on submit it shows please enter message, vice versa also I didn't enter this field no validation show. Whats the problem behind it? The issue only for the fields using ReactQuill.